# Windows Server 2016 Cipher Suites not working

Tags: powershell, encryption, ado.net, tls1.2, wireshark

I'm trying to connect to the Exasol database using Powershell with ADO.NET driver.
I can successfully connect from my Windows 10 PC, but can't from Windows Server 2016.
The error message is:

```
Error: SSL authentication failed. AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
Error: Inner exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
Debug: Exasol.EXADataProvider.EXAClientException (0x80004005): TLS connection to host (exadb1) failed: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
   at Exasol.EXADataProvider.backend.BackendFactory.ConnectToServer(String hostIp, Int32 serverPort, String serverName, String userFingerprint)
   at Exasol.EXADataProvider.backend.BackendFactory.PerformLogin(EXAConnectionStringBuilder connectString)
```

I checked that TLS 1.2 is enabled on Windows Server.
I thought, maybe Windows Server doesn't have proper Cipher Suites, which Exasol accepts.

Below is what `Get-TlsCipherSuite` command returns on my computer. Last column shows which Cipher Suites were mentioned in Wireshark log.

| Name | Certificate | Cipher | CipherLength | Wireshark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 |  | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 |  | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 |  |  | 0 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | ECDSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 | Client & Server Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 |  |  | 0 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | ECDSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | ECDSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | ECDSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA | RSA | 3DES | 168 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 | RSA |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA | RSA |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 |  | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 |  | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 |  | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256 |  |  | 0 |  |

Here is result of `Get-TlsCipherSuite` command on Windows Server 2016. Last column shows which Cipher Suites were mentioned in Wireshark log.

| Name | Certificate | Cipher | CipherLength | Wireshark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | ECDSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | ECDSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | ECDSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | ECDSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | ECDSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 256 | Client & Server Hello |
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 | RSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | RSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | RSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA | RSA | 3DES | 168 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 | DSA | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA | DSA | AES | 256 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA | DSA | AES | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA | DSA | 3DES | 168 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA | RSA | RC4 | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 | RSA | RC4 | 128 | Client Hello |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 | RSA |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA | RSA |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 |  | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 |  | AES | 256 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 |  | AES | 128 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384 |  |  | 0 |  |
| TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256 |  |  | 0 |  |

For some reason lists of Cipher Suites in Powershell and Wireshark don't match.

Do you know how to "activate" Cipher Suites on Windows Server? Why some of them are not used? Looks like Exasol would like to use `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, but Windows Server for some reason can't use it.

Comment: Looks like that cipher suite is supposed to be turned on at priority 3 by default in Server 2016 v1607 (with the possible exception of when it's running in FIPS mode). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1607

Comment: Does [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol return tls12, tls13? (You did say you checked, just double checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, setting `SystemDefaultTlsVersions` and `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry keys helped.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Before this change, `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` was returning `Ssl3, Tls`. After the change it started to return `SystemDefault`. And no more errors occur.

Also, I checked, now `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` cipher suite is used now.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: Had similar problem worked great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enable-TlsCipherSuite` to add additional ciphers to your server.

`Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"`

The above in an elevated powershell instance should give you an idea of where to go next

Comment: I ran `Enable-TlsCipherSuite` command for 6 top cipher suites. Nothing changed. They didn't appear in Wireshark log, and connection failed again. I simply don't understand why Powershell knows about cipher suites but is not using them?

Comment: Did you restart the machine after applying ?

Answer (score 0):

Try enforcing the tls protocol at the start of your script:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
```

Comment: It didn't help. Still the same error.